# Symfony - how to disable/readonly select which can hold data on submit?

Tags: symfony, select, disable

If you disable select, data of that select will not be added do response. How to prevent user not to dropdown select and hold data at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that using simple onclick event....in bootstrap dropdown you have your tag select and also you have some html added by bootstrap, find BUTTON tag which open your dropdown and get it DATA as selector
`$('button[data-id="xxxxxx"]').on('click',event => { return false; })`